# Dont want to copy hidden rows in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in which I created a button to delete the row and the option to Copy: My Issue is the remove button is working fine, however, after removing the row it still coping the removed row which I don't want you can run code snippet for a working example. What I Want is after removing the row the copy button only copy the visible rows, not the hidden one... please help 
thanks in advance:

```js
// Code for Remove Rows
$('.table tbody').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
// Code For Export Option           
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#enquirytable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy',
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="enquirytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>admission_no</th>
      <th>roll_no</th>
      <th>Action </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Student 1</td>
      <td>95</td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Student 2</td>
      <td>105</td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Student 3</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing row from html but it needs to be removed from datatable object too.
Set datatable in a variable and remove row using it and redraw the table. 
see below code

```
 // Code For Export Option           
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var enquiryTable = $('#enquirytable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 
        ]
    });

   $('.table tbody').on('click', '.btn', function(){
        enquiryTable
        .row( $(this).closest('tr') )
        .remove()
        .draw();
   });
 });
```

Comment: happy to help you :)